# Why do we need 4 points for homography but 7/8 points for fundamental matrix calculation?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision, homography

Sorry if this is a trivial question but I could not find a suitable answer elsewhere.

I recently learned about homography and fundamental matrices in a CV class. I understand how these matrices are calculated and how the the formulae are derived. I also understand that both homography and fundamental matrices have 8 degrees of freedom.

But I'm unable to understand why we need 4 point correspondences for finding the homography while 8 points for calculating the fundamental matrix.

Shouldn't the number of correspondences needed be same intuitively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because in the case of fundamental matrix, each correspondence point relates to only one constraint(i.e it maps a point to a line in other image). Hence 8 correspondence points are required.

But in the case of homography, each correspondence solves two constraints. Hence only 4 correspondence points are sufficient.

Comment: Great answer! And solving this constraints is visible in the derivation of the two matrices. I was just wondering would it be possible to

Comment: possible to what ?

Comment: oh looks like I posted my comment before I was done. As I said, great answer. The planar assumption explains each corresponding solving two constraints. I was just wondering what constraints are relaxed because of the planar assumption in homography. 

I guess you made a typo in the last sentence, eight point algorithm is used for estimating fundamental matrix and it indeed requires eight correspondences. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

consider the number of DOFs and number of constraints.

On the one hand, the matrix `H` contains 9 entries, but is defined only up to scale. Thus, the total number of degrees of freedom in a 2D projective transformation is 8.

On the other hand, each point-to-point correspondence accounts for two constraints, since for each point `x_i` in the first image the two DOFs of the point in the second image must correspond to the mapped point `H*x_i`. A 2D point has two DOFs to `(x,y)` components, each of which may be specified separately.

Alternatively, the point is specified as a homogeneous 3-vector, which also has 2 DOFs since scale is arbitrary. As a consequence, *it is necessary to specify four point correspondences* in order to constrain `H` fully.

## Rule of Thumb

- Number of constraints must *equal or exceed* the number of DOFs of the transformation.

## Example

In 2D each corresponding point or line generates two constraints on `H`, in 3D  each  corresponding  point  or  plane  generates  three  constraints.

Thus  in  2D  the correspondence of four points or four lines is sufficient to compute `H`, since `4×2=8` , with 8 the number of DOFs of the homography. In 3D a homography has 15 DOFs, and five points or five planes are required.  For a planar affine transformation (6 DOFs) only three corresponding points or lines are required, and so on.